# Problems Configuring IPTABLE for Samba Share

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, centos6

I am trying to configure Samba on my CentOS 6 server such that only 3 IP addresses have access to the Samba Share.  For some reason my iptable configuration is wrong.  I have checked lines 11-15 and each have a problem, I would assume it is the same problem.  Can someone see my problem?

```
[user_sa@host ~]$ sudo cat -n /etc/sysconfig/iptables
     1  # Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
     2  # Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
     3  *filter
     4  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
     5  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
     6  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
     7  -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
     8  -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
     9  -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    10  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    11  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.114/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
    12  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.114/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
    13  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.114/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
    14  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.114/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
    15  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.114/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
    16  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.115/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
    17  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.115/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
    18  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.115/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
    19  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.115/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
    20  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.115/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
    21  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.116/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
    22  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.116/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
    23  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.116/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
    24  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.116/32 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
    25  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.116/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
    26  -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    27  -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    28  COMMIT
[user_sa@host ~]$ sudo service iptables restart
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 11 failed
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
4  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
5  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
6  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
(snip)    
11  -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.114/32 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
```

You're using an undefined chain (`RH-Firewall-1-INPUT`).

It seems you copy/pasted the `ACCEPT` rules from some website without understanding what it actually does. That's...not a good idea. No matter the source of new information, always try and do research on your own to understand what the commands actually do before using them.

Comment: @andrew https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables is a good place to start reading the docs.